# React - onMouseDown/onMouseUp not triggered for left click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm working with mouse events on a HTML Canvas in a react component, but have an issue where the onMouseDown/onMouseUp aren't triggered with a left click on the mouse. It works for right click and center click.

```
handleMouseDown(event)
{
    console.log("mouse down");
}

handleMouseMove(event)
{
    console.log("mouse move");
}

handleMouseUp(event)
{
    console.log("mouse up");
}

render() {
    return (
        <div
            className="chart">
            <canvas
                id="canvas"
                onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
                onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove.bind(this)}
                onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    );
```

Anyone experiences this before?

**Edit**
Note: I am trying to get the X/Y coordinates of where the mouse down event occurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `onClick` for left-clicks:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event){
    const yCoord = event.y;
    const xCoord = event.x;
    console.log("Y Coordinate = " + yCoord + 
    "\n X Coordinate = " + xCoord + ".");
    
    switch(event.which) {
      case 1: {
        console.log('Left Mouse button pressed.');
        break;
      }
      case 2: {
        console.log('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
        break;
      }
      case 3: {
        console.log('Right Mouse button pressed.');
        break;
      }
      default: {
        console.log('You have a strange Mouse!');
      }
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="chart">
        <canvas id="canvas" 
          onClick={(e) =>{this.handleClick(e.nativeEvent)}}
          onContextMenu={(e) =>
            {this.handleClick(e.nativeEvent)}}>
        </canvas>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.chart {
  width: 100;
  height: 100;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 50;
  height: 50;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: While this does work, I'm working on a graph and need the x/y coordinates of the mouse down.

Comment: No worries, the x/y coordinates of the mouse down can also be found in the `event` object. See the updated answer for how to get that information.

Comment: Thanks andrew, that's definitely getting me some result, but it still leaves me with the issue where I need the event as soon as the user clicks. onClick seems to only tricker after mousing up, but for me I need to be able to click on an object on screen and drag to another position. What's strange is that I have another application where the mouse events work just fine, but can't see what I'm doing thats different.

Comment: Got this working Andrew. I added a second canvas on top of the other one and the events are now working. Thanks for the help!